# DBContext.Entry(Entity).Property(fieldname) stopped working after upgrading to dotnet core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a generic method that I call to add a detached entity to the DBContext

After the update the GetProperties does not return none nullable TimeSpan properties.

```
public void AddEntity<T>(DbSet<T> entityList, T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    DBContext.Entry(entity).Metadata.GetProperties()
}
```

Comment: May be a bug was fixed.  In c# a DateTime nor a TimeSpan can be null.  The old interface probably allowed a null (an error) while new version fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with dotnet core 2.2

The newer version of dotnet core is more strict.

In the generated class I had

```
public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
```

In the generated partial class I had

```
[NotMapped]
TimeSpan? ISchedule.StartTime

[NotMapped]
TimeSpan? ISchedule.EndTime
```

In the new version the [NotMapped] attribute suppresses both StartTime properties